# how to open datepicker on button click or icon click in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am using this datepicker in my demo application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
but my datepicker opens when I clicked on input field.**can we open date picker when user click on button and icon on right side instead of input click  ?**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import "./styles.css";

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  openDatePicker = () => {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.openDatePicker}>openDate</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to make it open other than clicking the component itself. You can control it by using the `open` property of the Datepicker. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import "./styles.css";

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      datePickerIsOpen: false,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.openDatePicker = this.openDatePicker.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  openDatePicker() {
    this.setState({
      datePickerIsOpen: !this.state.datePickerIsOpen,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.openDatePicker}>openDate</button>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onClickOutside={this.openDatePicker}
          open={this.state.datePickerIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

As you can see, we have added a state to the Example class, which controls the `open` property of the Datepicker. I also added the onClickOutside, which can be used to determine what should happen if the user clicks outside the datepicker once it's open.

Comment: Can you implement it with functional component style.. this is old way

Comment: Really appreciate this answer. I was looking for the same in their docs where they listed the props, and couldn't find any details about the 'open' prop. In fact which is more relevant in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the button as a customInput

```
import React from 'react'

const CustomInput = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

    return (
       <button onClick={props.onClick} ref={ref}>
         {props.value || props.placeholder}
       </button>
    )

})

export default CustomInput;
```

Then in the main component. do this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput"
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import "./styles.css";

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          customInput={<CustomInput />}
          placeholderText="openDate"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```